# UITableView does not respond to touches at transparent areas

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, quartz-core

I have a `UITableView` with a transparent `backgroundColor`, and the cells inside are initialized with the following code

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.frame), 180)];
    self.label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.label.text = @"test";
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.label];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Each row has a height of 200, and the label doesn't fill up the entire cell. There will be transparent portions in between each cell. When I try to scroll the table by touching those transparent portions, the touches are completely ignored. I am aware that as of iOS5, touches on  views will be ignored. What can I do to solve this?

Things I've tried that don't work:

*Setting a transparent or hidden or alpha = 0 `UIView` to act as a fake background of the tableView*

Same deal, touches are ignored.

*Creating a subclassed `UIView` on top of the tableView, and the subclassed `UIView` uses tableView as the nextResponder*

Apparently `UITableView` doesn't use touchesBegan/cancelled/ended/moved, so this doesn't work. I don't think it's wise to implement my methods to scroll the `UITableView` either.

*Setting the backgroundColor of the tableView to `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.1]`*

I don't want to do this, it's still visible.

In short, **what can I do to scroll the table even when I start the scrolling from the transparent section?**

Comment: Dear @Augustine, you can accomplish your task by other delegate scrolling methods (available in `UIScrollview`).Can you please throw some light why you want to work with the `touchesBegan` method ?

Comment: I was thinking I could use touchesBegan to intercept the touch before it gets ignored due to the touched area being transparent, but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried putting in scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewWillBeginDragging: in the delegate of the tableView, but neither is called when I start the scrolling from the transparent section.


PS How do you set the grey background for keywords? Like what you've done for UIScrollview and touchesBegan in your comment.

Comment: For the grey color, use write your words between `` (the button left to key 1: press it twice and write your words in between them) :)

Answer (score 0):

First you create a label with no text(or a view) such that it completely fills the cell. Then create a new label with your text and add this as a subview of the first view.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately, it still gets ignored when I make the first view have a `[UIColor clearColor]` for `backgroundColor`